# Deleting file from git cache

Tags: sublimetext2

How to auto delete file from Git cache when I deleted it by hand in sublime text 2? Is there a plugin to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is the way you can remove file/folders from `git cache` manually.**

Remove tracking of file/folder - but keep them on disk - using

```
$ git rm --cached
```

Now they do not show up as "changed" but still show as
untracked files in

```
$ git status -u
```

Add them to     `.gitignore`

Use

```
$ git config --global core.editor
```

Comment: I would like it to be in the Sublime Text 2.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the definite file which you want to ignore, rather than removing all files in cache, it will reduce risk.

1. add to `.gitignore`;
2. delete the file/files `git rm cached <file>`